# Google Cloud Messaging iOS library doesn't have armv7s slice

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I setup Google Cloud Messaging iOS library by following the official site(below), and built my app.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift#set_up_your_cocoapods_dependencies

Then I found a module inside doesn't have armv7s slice.

```
File is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/.../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a' for architecture armv7s
```

I think there is no way to use this library if your app supports armv7s, but really appreciate it if anyone knows any workaround.

Comment: The default standard architectures in Xcode hasn't included armv7s since Xcode 6.0. I'm guessing the GCM people just build the default architectures; that's why it doesn't have armv7s. Why do you need armv7s?

Comment: @user102008, c/z we need to support iPhone5 and iPhone5c.

Comment: Yes, and so does the default architectures setting in Xcode. Any device that can run armv7s code can also run armv7 code.

Comment: @user102008 Are you sure ? When I had submitted an app with arm64 and armv7 support, I got claim from iPhone5 users that they couldn't see my app on AppStore. So I believe even the code is compatible, the app will be invisible to iPhone5 and 5c users which was what I experienced.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Most apps have just arm64 and armv7 and they have plenty of users on iPhone 5 and 5C.